# Is it possible to define table relations with multiple keys in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Say for example I have in table `SITES` a unique key set to include fields `site, permission` and I want to use a foreign key to keep the same reference keyed to match `site, permission` in table `USERS`. Is it possible to create a relation that uses multi-key indexes in mysql? I can resolve this programmatically also, however I would prefer to keep referential integrity constrained to the data layer if at all possible. Using single relations could potentially lead to a record being inserted with the wrong permission but the correct site, or vice versa.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: short answer: Yes, you can

Comment: Well that makes my life a lot easier then. Do you know the syntax for this, or a link to where I can research it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in my comment: Yes, you can have constraints that use multiple columns.

You can check [MySQL Reference Manual: Using `FOREIGN KEY` constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Quoting from the reference, the syntax is:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
```

As you can see, you can have multiple columns in the constraint. Of course (more exactly, obviously), they must match, and they must be indexed in both tables.